# Printing PDF with CUPS

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, printing, cups

We have two different Kyocera printers running for printing invoices. The invoices are PDF files that have been generated by wkhtmltopdf (previously dompdf with the same issues). Printing these invoices used to work fine, but suddenly without any interference only part of the files are printed. Different invoices result in different but all still broken prints. I'm talking about e.g. four lines of text and a single rectangle, or the lines of a table and the image header only.

CUPS, which I'm using to print, shows me the following error for each PDF:

```
W [12/Nov/2016:09:45:01 +0100] [Job 80] /var/spool/cups/d00080-001: file is damaged
W [12/Nov/2016:09:45:01 +0100] [Job 80] /var/spool/cups/d00080-001 (file     position 34956): xref not found
W [12/Nov/2016:09:45:01 +0100] [Job 80] /var/spool/cups/d00080-001: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table
```

I am clueless as to why this happens, as every other PDF reader can show generated invoices just fine. Printing the same files with Acrobat Reader will not cause any of these problems.

What part of the system is causing this problem? How did this start happening suddenly without me (the only one touching the printing system) even being at the office. Is there a workaround?

PS: The printers are a Kyocera ECOSYS P2135dn and a Kyocera FS-1370DN. Both using their identically named official driver installed from the kyocera website. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with CUPS 2.1.3.

Comment: I'd be tempted to hunt around to see what has changed, whether within the application, the OS, or the printers.

Comment: Where would I start? I have been away for a week. The application generating the PDFs is still at the same revision, the OS has only done its unattended security updates, and the printers do not even try to update automatically.

Comment: check you are not running out of disk space.

Comment: I've just checked that. The application and printer servers are both fine on disk and inode usage.

Comment: What happens if you convert one of the PDFs that won't print to Postscript, and print the resulting postscript?

Comment: I've converted an invoice to Postscript using `pdf2ps`. It made the file 30x bigger, but it printed out fine using the exact same method. The small lines do seem to have vanished though. Is this explainable?

Comment: One of the two printers doesn't print the PS file, it will show that it's receiving data indefinitely. When manually cancelled, it will delete data indefinitely. The PS file is about 1MiB in total.